# Stack data structure array is not being recognized in functions

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have written C++ code for a stack. I am getting an error that array 'a' has not been declared in the scopes of push, pop and display functions. I have tried to remove private but the problem still persists. How can I fix this?

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class stack
{
    private:
        int n;
        int a[10];
        int top;    
    public:
        stack(int n);
        void push(int x);
        int pop();
        void display();
};

stack::stack(int q)
{
    n=q;
    top=-1;
}

void stack::push(int x)
{
    if(top==n-1)
        cout<<"\nStack overflow\n";
    else
        a[++top]=x;
}

int stack::pop()
{
    if(top==-1)
        cout<<"\nStack is empty\n";
    else
        return (a[top--]);
}

void stack::display()
{
    int i;
    for(i=top;i>=0;i--)
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"\nEnter the size of stack\n";
    cin>>n;
    stack st(n);
    int i,x;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"\nSelect option 1.Push 2.Pop 3.Display\n";
        cin>>i;
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1: cin>>x;
                st.push(x);
                break;
            case 2: st.pop();
                break;
            case 3: st.display();
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? And could you show us the command you use to compile? That examples compiles and runs fine for  me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c23210725c0799a.  Besides mising a `return` in `pop` the code compiles

Comment: @bznein - I'm using gedit and then typing g++ stack.cpp in command line.

Comment: Some indentation would have been nice...

Comment: I copied your code and compiled with gcc 5.1.1. The code does not work as you might have expected, but it compiles. So I can not reproduce your problem. Can you please add your compiler error messages?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with visual studio 2008.

Comment: I don't know why it wasn't working. I have now tried the same code using geany and it worked fine. Suprisingly, after it worked in geany, it worked in g++. Strange.